# How to Sync Data between modules in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS how do we sync sub modules data when the one of them is updated.

In example below myService is shared among otherApp and myApp. If we click reset data does not get sync.

```js
var otherApp = angular.module('otherApp', []);
otherApp.factory('myService', function() {
  var myService = {
    someData: ''
  };
  return myService;
});
otherApp.controller('otherCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.shared = myService;
});


var app = angular.module('myApp', ['otherApp']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.shared = myService;
  
  $scope.reset = function (){
    $scope.shared = {someData:0};
    
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="otherCtrl">
    <span>otherCtrl:</span>
    <input ng-model="shared.someData" placeholder="Type here..">
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <span>myCtrl:</span>
  <input ng-model="shared.someData" placeholder="Type here..">
    
    <button ng-click="reset()">reset</button>
  </div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not modifying the data inside the shared service. You're assigning a new object to the `shared` attribute of your controller scope: instead of referencing the service, this attribute now references another object. So only that controller scope is affected. The other controller's `$scope.share` is still referencing the service.

Replace

```
$scope.shared = {someData:0};
```

by

```
$scope.shared.someData = 0;
```